# Adding Azure Logic App step for Form Recognizer 2.0 has issue with built in connection

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer

Success:
Have been trying out form recognizer and it has been pretty awesome tool thus far. I am able to use Postman and C# to train and analyze jpeg images.

Issue:
Tried to take form recognizer a step further and connect it to logic app. Followed this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/tutorial-form-recognizer-with-logic-apps). I have called the most simple case GetModels and logic app call returned [] empty data set. When I run end point via postman I do receive several models in json body.

I have tried debugging for a little while and believe issue could be version of form recognizer.
I think logic app form recognizer calls "{BaseURI}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models" instead of "{BaseURI}/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models".

I have had similar experience with formrecognizer SDK in C# where I can clearly see that SDK was calling v1.0-preview and maybe Logic App built in step is using same SDK under the hood.

If anyone has experienced same issues please help!

Comment: You can try moving the logic (form recognizer) to an Azure function and call it in your logic app workflow

Comment: So build Azure function using c# dll which I got to work in separate test app and then attach custom Azure function instead of Azure Built in Form Recognizer. I will circle back later if this works...

Answer (score 1):

Form Recognizer logic app built in connector is still using the Form Recognizer v1 release and is not yet updated to the v2 release. To call the Form Recognizer v2 release you can create a custom connector in logic app.

SDKs for Form Recognizer v2 (preview) release are now available: 
.NET SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer
JAVA SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer
Python SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer
Java Script SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/ai-form-recognizer

Comment: Thanks @Neta I believe c# .net SDK is still referencing version 1.0

Comment: This one is referencing v2.0 - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer

Comment: The library's [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3780001351c64f9d29eafe3913f7361fde8b6fbd/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/CHANGELOG.md) lists the service version(s) it supports.  The .NET SDK version 1.0.0-preview.1 supports the Form Recognizer service v2.0-preview API.